# DB2 Index over two Date fields

Tags: indexing, db2

I am quite new to DB2 and i want to support my query with an index over two date columns:

```
WHERE (t0.start_date <= ? AND (t0.till_date > ? OR t0.till_date IS 
    NULL))
```

Is there an optimal way to place the index or is it better just to index till_date?

Second question is do i have to manually put indexes on foreign key columns?

best regards,
m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In multi-column indexes it is better to have columns with higher cardinalities (most distinct values) towards the beginning. In your example, assuming `start_date` is never null and `till_date` can be null, it would be better to build the index on `start_date, till_date`.

DB2 does not automatically create indexes for referential integrity constraints. It requires a unique or primary key constraint on the parent columns, and those do create indexes automatically, but you will have to manually create the corresponding index on the child table.

Comment: "In multi-column indexes it is better to have columns with higher cardinalities" is correct in this case but not in general. Here it is correct because both predicates involve range predicates (as opposed to equals). http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/greater-less-between-tuning-sql-access-filter-predicates

Comment: @MarkusWinand So you're saying that for an equality predicate and a table of 1 mln rows containing columns `last_name` and `gender`, an index on `gender, last_name` would be preferable to the one on `last_name, gender`?

Comment: No. It depends on the comparison operators you are using. If you are using only equality operators—which seems to be reasonable for gender & last_name—it just doesn't matter order to use. If, hover, you'd use a greater-than operator for last_name, then (gender, last_name) would be better.